# How can effectively use dynamic CSS in a mobile browser?

Tags: asp.net, iphone, css, blackberry, mobile

I am trying to develop a mobile version of my web application and I am having trouble getting it to look good on multiple browsers.  I figure if I use some device capability detection I can dynamically generate widths and font-sizes based on a particular devices screen size.  The problem is that it seems like a mobile browser doesn't treat 1px of CSS width equal to 1px of screen width.  On an iPhone with a screen width of 320px, a body tag that is 320px wide takes up only about a 1/4th of the page.  With no real frame of reference, it makes it hard for me to say "On a screen of 320px wide, make the font 16px" or something along those lines.  Is there some general rule of thumb I can use to calculate the real browser width in CSS, or some calculation using multiple device capabilities that will help me generate dynamic CSS more effectively?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining sizes and font weights in relative units. I would give % and em a go. Many mobile browsers try to scale everything down so that they render normal websites nicely. You may find you need specialy meta tags or the like to controll these browsers.

Comment: You're right, and the tag I found that controls this is:
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
After using this it appears that dynamic css isn't as necessary since the browser will be zoomed out to a 1:1 pixel ratio.  Then things like block elements work more effectively to stretch out the screen size.